# OS X, Screenlock

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, security, electron

I have wanted to write my own lock-screen for a very very long time, I have never succeeded because of Force Quit and a few other backdoors to exit the electron window, such as swiping and CTRL+C (^C), I have been able to create a lock-screen on Windows (.NET CSharp) and Linux(Kali, c++). There was obviously backdoors but still better than my progress on OS X, I don't like to use the default lock-screen, even after changing the background of the lock-screen as well, it just feels like there is no life in it and I'd like to create my own so I have something to also be some what proud of.

I am creating my project in Node.JS Electron because JavaScript is a language I know quite well and I wish to be even better at it, I have worked for a very long time to try override default events on shortcuts and so on so I could not get passed the lock-screen without typing the correct password. I'd also like a better solution for validating the password, currently I'm using the input from the textarea and using the sudo command from the child node. It does work, but it is somewhat buggy.

Possible solutions is to disable shortcuts, swiping, force quit, spotlight, topmost apps, etc that can come over the electron window, disabling ^C, and so on. But I'd like if I could add it manually and implement it to the Apple system. Or replace the already existing lock-screen.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use kiosk mode. When initializing your `BrowserWindow`, add `kiosk: true`.

Comment: How do you disable `CMD` + `TAB`

Comment: Or, alternatively pad swiping

Comment: There's a lot of key combinations that you can get around kiosk mode, but in my case at least swiping or cmd+tab won't work as long as you make the window top most. You can still exit it by option+brightness or option+volume, etc.